# Need an alternative for AsyncTask in Kotlin, I know to use Caroutines,Executors, Handlers but unsure how to implement in my google maps koltin app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I am building a google maps routing app and i cant build as AsyncTask is depreceiated, I know to use caroutines/executers/handlers but I dont know how to implement them in my code as I have followed several tutorials and unsure. I am building a google maps app using maps and directions API's and I am having an issue with AsyncTask being depreciated.

Here is My download task function:

```
inner class DownloadTask :
        AsyncTask<String?, Void?, String>(){

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val parserTask = ParserTask()
            parserTask.execute(result)
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
            var data = ""
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0].toString()).toString()
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString())
            }
            return data
        }

        }
```

and here is my parser task for parsing into JSON with data parser class

```
//parsing into JSON format
    inner class ParserTask :
        AsyncTask<String?, Int?, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?> () {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg jsonData: String?): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
            val jObject: JSONObject
            var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? =
                null
            try {
                jObject = JSONObject(jsonData[0])
                val parser = DataParser()
                routes = parser.parse(jObject)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return routes
        }


        override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?) {
            val points = ArrayList<LatLng?>()
            val lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
            for (i in result!!.indices) {
                val path =
                    result[i]
                for (j in path.indices) {
                    val point = path[j]
                    val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                    val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                    val position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                    points.add(position)
                }
                lineOptions.addAll(points)
                lineOptions.width(8f)
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED)
                lineOptions.geodesic(true)
            }

            if (points.size != 0) mMap!!.addPolyline(lineOptions)
        }

    }
```

if anybody could help me with how I can use Executor and Handler with this code, that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my full MainActivity file for reference.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback
    //, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener
{

    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

    lateinit var mapView: MapView

    private val MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey"

    private val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f

    lateinit var B_search: Button

    lateinit var tvCurrentAddress: TextView

    private var fusedLocationProviderClient : FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

    var end_latitude = 0.0

    var end_longitude = 0.0

    lateinit var origin: MarkerOptions

    lateinit var destination:MarkerOptions

    var latitude = 0.0

    var longitude = 0.0

    private val myExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private val myHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

        mapView.onResume()
        mMap = googleMap

        askPermissionLocation()

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        mMap!!.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraMoveListener (this)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this)
//        mMap!!.setOnCameraIdleListener(this)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mapView = findViewById<MapView>(R.id.map1)

        tvCurrentAddress = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAdd)

        B_search = findViewById(R.id.B_search)

        askPermissionLocation()

        var mapViewBundle: Bundle? = null
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        }

        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)


        B_search.setOnClickListener {

            searchArea()
        }

    }

    private fun searchArea() {
        val tf_location =
            findViewById<View>(R.id.TF_location) as EditText

        val location = tf_location.text.toString()

        var addressList: List<Address>? = null

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()

        if (location != "") {
            val geocoder = Geocoder (applicationContext)
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (addressList != null) {
                for (i in addressList.indices) {
                    val myAddress = addressList[i]
                    val latLng =
                        LatLng(myAddress.latitude, myAddress.longitude)
                    markerOptions.position(latLng)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    end_latitude = myAddress.latitude
                    end_longitude = myAddress.longitude

                    mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))

                    val mo = MarkerOptions()
                    mo.title("Distance")

                    val results = FloatArray(10)
                    Location.distanceBetween(
                        latitude,
                        longitude,
                        end_latitude,
                        end_longitude,
                        results
                    )

                    val s =
                        String.format("%.1f", results[0] / 1000)


                    //Setting marker to draw route between these two points
                    origin = MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title("HSR Layout").snippet("origin")
                    destination =
                        MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(end_latitude, end_longitude))
                            .title(tf_location.text.toString())
                            .snippet("Distance = $s KM")
                    mMap!!.addMarker(destination)
                    mMap!!.addMarker(origin)

                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Distance = $s KM",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ) .show()


                    tvCurrentAddress!!.setText("Distance = $s KM")

                    //getting URL to the google Directions API
                    val url: String=
                        getDirectionsUrl(origin!!.getPosition(), destination!!.getPosition())!!

                    val downloadTask: DownloadTask = DownloadTask()

                    //start downloading the json data from google directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun downloadUrl(strUrl: String) : String?{
        var data = ""
        var iStream: InputStream? = null
        var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        try{
            val url = URL(strUrl)
            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnection.connect()
            iStream = urlConnection!!.inputStream
            val br =
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(iStream))
            val sb = StringBuffer()
            var line: String? = ""
            while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                sb.append(line)
            }
            data = sb.toString()
            br.close()
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString())
        } finally {
            iStream!!.close()
            urlConnection!!.disconnect()
        }
        return data
    }

    inner class DownloadTask :
        AsyncTask<String?, Void?, String>(){

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val parserTask = ParserTask()
            parserTask.execute(result)
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
            var data = ""
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0].toString()).toString()
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString())
            }
            return data
        }

        }

    //parsing into JSON format
    inner class ParserTask :
        AsyncTask<String?, Int?, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?> () {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg jsonData: String?): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
            val jObject: JSONObject
            var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? =
                null
            try {
                jObject = JSONObject(jsonData[0])
                val parser = DataParser()
                routes = parser.parse(jObject)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return routes
        }


        override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?) {
            val points = ArrayList<LatLng?>()
            val lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
            for (i in result!!.indices) {
                val path =
                    result[i]
                for (j in path.indices) {
                    val point = path[j]
                    val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                    val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                    val position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                    points.add(position)
                }
                lineOptions.addAll(points)
                lineOptions.width(8f)
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED)
                lineOptions.geodesic(true)
            }

            if (points.size != 0) mMap!!.addPolyline(lineOptions)
        }

    }

    private fun getDirectionsUrl(origin: LatLng, dest: LatLng): String?{
        //Origin of route
        val str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude

        //Destination of Route
        val str_destination = "destination" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude

        //transportation mode
        val mode = "mode=walking"

        //building parameters of webservice
        val parameters = "$str_origin&$str_destination&$mode"

        //output format
        val output = "json"

        //building the url to the web service
        return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/$output?$parameters&key=AIzaSyCgraKSwPfUIyZLOmEDh_ptAbfRRAj7y1g"
    }

    public override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        askPermissionLocation()
        var mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
        if (mapViewBundle == null){
            mapViewBundle = Bundle()
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle)
        }

        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle)
    }

    private fun askPermissionLocation(){
        askPermission(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ){

            getCurrentLocation()
//            mapView.getMapAsync(this@MyNavigationActivity)

        }
    }

    private fun askPermission(accessFineLocation: String, accessCoarseLocation: String, function: () -> Unit) {

    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient =
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this@MainActivity)

        try {
            @SuppressLint ("MissingPermission")
            val location =
                fusedLocationProviderClient!!.getLastLocation()

            location.addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<Location> {
                override fun onComplete(loc: Task<Location>) {
                    if (loc.isSuccessful) {

                        val currentLocation = loc.result as Location?
                        if (currentLocation != null) {
                            moveCamera(
                                LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM
                            )

                            latitude = currentLocation.latitude
                            longitude = currentLocation.longitude

                        }
                    } else {
                        askPermissionLocation()
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (se: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Security Exception")
        }
    }

    private fun moveCamera(latLng: LatLng, zoom: Float) {
       // mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom))
    }


//    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
//       val geocoder = Geocoder (this, Locale.getDefault())
//       var addresses: List<Address>? = null
//       try {
//           addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location!!.latitude, location.longitude, 1)
//       } catch (e: IOException) {
//           e.printStackTrace()
//       }
//       setAddress(addresses!![0])
//    }
//
//    private fun setAddress(addresses: Address) {
//        if (addresses != null) {
//
//            if (addresses.getAddressLine(0) != null) {
//                tvCurrentAddress!!.setText(addresses.getAddressLine(0))
//            }
//            if (addresses.getAddressLine(1) != null) {
//                tvCurrentAddress!!.setText(
//                        tvCurrentAddress.getText().toString() + addresses.getAddressLine(1)
//                )
//            }
//        }
//    }
//
//
//
//    override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraMove() {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraMoveStarted(p0: Int) {
//
//    }
//
//    override fun onCameraIdle() {
//        var addresses: List<Address>? = null
//        val geocoder = Geocoder (this, Locale.getDefault())
//        try {
//            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation( mMap!!.getCameraPosition().target.latitude, mMap!!.getCameraPosition().target.longitude, 1)
//
//            setAddress(addresses!![0])
//
//        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        } catch (e: IOException) {
//            e.printStackTrace()
//        }
//    }


}
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if you specifically describe what you got stuck on and show your code so far. Otherwise, how can we be any more helpful than the tutorials you followed without writing complete tutorials ourselves and just hoping we hit the details that the other ones lacked?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added in my complete MainActivity.kt file for reference. I am trying to plot a route between two points, in my app the user can search an address and then I want the app to plot a route from current location to the specified address

Comment: I meant your code after trying to implement either coroutines or executors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with coroutines. I cannot execute you code on my side but i tried to converted it into Coroutine.

***Please note here i am using GLobalScope you must need to use other relevant scope if this code you will add in Activity you can create custom scope.***

```
fun func () {

    GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
        val result = parseDataAndGetRoutes()
        
        val points = ArrayList<LatLng?>()
        val lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        for (i in result!!.indices) {
            val path =
                result[i]
            for (j in path.indices) {
                val point = path[j]
                val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                val position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                points.add(position)
            }
            lineOptions.addAll(points)
            lineOptions.width(8f)
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED)
            lineOptions.geodesic(true)
        }

        if (points.size != 0) mMap!!.addPolyline(lineOptions)
    }
}

suspend fun parseDataAndGetRoutes() : List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
        val jObject: JSONObject
        var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? = null
        try {
            jObject = JSONObject(jsonData[0])
            val parser = DataParser()
            routes = parser.parse(jObject)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return@withContext routes
    }
```